# GRUB can't find root files Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, live-usb, 20.04

Just tried to clean install my computer with the newest Ubuntu but it takes me immediately to grub.  My partition is saved at (hd0,msdos5) it seams.  I did the assignments as follows:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,5)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda5
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0.29-generic
grub> boot
```

But after boot I get the message that it **gave up waiting for rootfile system device**.  And then an **ALERT!  /dev/sda5 does not exist.  Dropint to a shell!** and then I'm stuck ash, I think.

Really not sure what to do here since I've never had this kind of issue before

Comment: Try using grub's tab completion to fill in the possible devices, and check them all.  So at the "set root=" type tab and see which devices are available, then use it and do same for partitions.